# ffmpeg convert .png to DNxHD .mov and scale color to bt709

Tags: ffmpeg

I have an 8bpc .png sequence in RGB color space (full range 0-255 of course) that I need to convert to DNxHD bt709 "legal" range (16-235). Here is where I am so far:

`ffmpeg -framerate 23.976 -i input_%04d.png -vcodec dnxhd -b:v 175M outfile.mov`

This throws an error: `pixel format is incompatible with DNxHD profile`. I used to do this all the time in a earlier version of ffmeg with no issue... I assume it has to do with the color space, and in looking through the "colorspace" filter documentation I am uncertain what the proper command would be. As mentioned I do want to actually transform the values to bt709, legal range.

Answer (score 2):

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24000/1001 -i input_%04d.png -vf format=yuv422p10le -c:v dnxhd -b:v 180M output.mov
```

- Use `24000/1001` or [`ntsc-film`](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Video-rate) instead of the inaccurate 23.976 byname.
- This encoder only supports the following pixel formats: `yuv422p`, `yuv422p10le`,  `yuv444p10le`,  `gbrp10le`. See `ffmpeg -h encoder=dnxhd`.
- This encoder only supports specific combinations of bitrate, width, and height. See a list with `ffmpeg -f lavfi -i nullsrc -c:v dnxhd -f null -`.
- bt709 should be automatically chosen, but verify it is what you want. See output of `ffmpeg -i output.mov`.

Comment: Thanks for the info but when I tried setting the format to yuv422p10le I experience some color shifting, particularly in green, and when sampling the output in a few different applications it is not "clean" in that some values go above and below legal range. From what I've read online "colorspace" seems the best way to handle this I am just unsure of the syntax.

Comment: Ok I did get this monster to work: `colorspace=space=bt709:trc=bt709:primaries=bt709:range=tv:format-yuv422p:iall=bt601-6-625` however I am still above/below legal range in some of the channels. Possibly this is due to compression... Anyway my question is what the input characteristics should be? I chose bt610-6-625 arbitrarily, and when I scan my pngs with Exiftool the only metadata I get is "RGB" but not color space. Visually this looks ok, so maybe it is fine?

Comment: PNGs typically are in sRGB colorspace - which has same primaries as bt709, but a different transfer function (gamma) and colorspace.